# Switching limits: $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $n\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I feel like this question may have already been asked, but despite my searches, I could not find it.

I am looking to prove that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{[b, b+\epsilon]} g=0$  for an integrable function $g$.  To do so, I would like to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, as $g$ is my integrable dominating function.  However, I realize that the DCT is defined for the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.  I am looking to somehow switch this $\epsilon$ for $\frac{1}{k}$ and then take $k$ to infinity and use DCT.  However, I feel that it cannot be so simple.  How do I go about applying DCT to limits which are not going to infinity?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{[b,b+\epsilon]}g=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_b^{b+\frac1n}g=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_b^{b+1}g(t)\chi_{[b,b+\frac1n]}(t)dt$$
so with $$\vert g_n(t)\vert=\vert g(t)\chi_{[b,b+\frac1n]}(t)\vert\le |g(t)|$$
you get the result using dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: That was my plan, but I was a bit hesitant to directly just switch it like that.  Can you really always just replace the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ with $n \rightarrow \infty$ and set $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: The answer is YES.

Comment: and the reason is...more or less Omnomnomnom's answer. The nasty thing is that you can't replace a claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n) = L$ (for integer $n$) with the claim that $\lim_ {\epsilon \to 0} f(\epsilon) = L$; it's quite possible for the first limit to exist but not the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of setting $\epsilon = 1/k$ can be made to work.  However, you need to make some adjustments to your argument:

- Note that it suffices to show that $\int_{[b,b+\epsilon]}|g|\to 0$
- Note that for $\epsilon \in [1/(k+1),1/k]$, we have
  $$ 
  \int_{[b,b+1/(k+1)]}|g| \leq
  \int_{[b,b+\epsilon]}|g| \leq 
  \int_{[b,b+1/k]}|g|
  $$

Now, use your argument to show that $\int_{[b,b+1/k]}|g| \to 0$, and by the above arguments that's enough.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why it works to say "for $\epsilon \in [\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k}]$."  Is it because for every $\epsilon$ such an interval exists, because rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: We're definitely not using the density of the rationals.  I am, however, saying that for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, there is a $k$ with $1/(k+1) \leq \epsilon \leq 1/k$. This is simply because $1/k$ gives a decreasing sequence with $1/k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.